# Are there limitations that should be taken into account when using Delete by query in SolrCloud?

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I mean regarding number of documents and/or total size being deleted together.

Let's say that we have a collection of news from many countries and it has the field subject that classifies the documents, but we want to delete all the "sport" ones, so:

`<delete> <query>subject:sport</query> </delete>`

Is it feasible for how many documents at once without having any issues?

Comment: Should probably be fine - it's hard to say what "many documents" mean in your case, and what kind of limitations you have for the service, but in any case a delete is "just" marking documents as deleted, they don't get removed until Solr run optimize on the index. Test it and see if it works as you expect, should be fine as long as your servers handle rewriting the index files fine.